# Webapi v1 routes are not adhered to

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ninject

The webapi call returns the error:

```
  message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:25396/api/dmpe/form/123'.",
  messageDetail: "No action was found on the controller 'Dmpe' that matches the request."
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetForm")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetForm(long formId)
    {
        try
        {
            var form = this.dmpeService.GetForm(formId);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, form);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = serializer.Serialize(new { success = false, message = e.Message });
            _logger.Error("GetForm Error: {0}", e.Message);

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, json);
        }

    }
```

WebApi route config:

```
   //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   //         name: "GetForm",
   //         routeTemplate: "api/dmpe/form/{id}",
   //         defaults: new
   //         {
   //             controller = "Dmpe",
   //             action = "GetForm"
   //         }
   //     );
```

Update route:

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetForm",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/form/{id}"
        );
```

I based the route off the naming convention currently in place. This route works.

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetMenu",
            routeTemplate: "api/forms/menu/{userTypeId}/{ctyhocn}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Service",
                action = "GetMenu"
            },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new[] { HttpMethod.Get.ToString() }) }
        );
```

Now in WebApi v2 I've been accustomed to defining the routes in the controller like below but that's a v2 feature I'm finding out. Based off the current example I would have thought the routeTemplate would work. I looked into the RouteTables.Routes for the route I defined and it appears to be in the correct format: "api/{controller}/form/{id}"

WebApi v2 route attributes

```
 [HttpGet]
 [AllowAnonymous]
 [Route("api/office/companynames/{searchValue}/")]
 .....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're getting has to do with how the route is configured and not Ninject.  Good practice for WebAPI (1.0 or 2.2) is to use the following template:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Unlike MVC, there is no action name included.

So, try playing with the route set up to see if you can get it to work.

Comment: Hello @Karen_B I'm following the routeTemplate convention currently in the app. For example this is a working route in the application <pre> config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "GetMenu",
                routeTemplate: "api/forms/menu/{userTypeId}/{ctyhocn}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Service",
                    action = "GetMenu"
                },
                constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new[] { HttpMethod.Get.ToString() }) }
            );</pre>

Comment: If I add a [FromBody] to the controller action the routeTemplate is used...sort of...because it doesn't get the actual id I pass in the url (/api/dmpe/form/123

Comment: Did you try [FromUri]? Unfortunately WebAPI v1 doesn't have the routing attributes like 2 does. However, I did stumble across a library some wrote to use route attributes in v1. Sorry I don't have the link anymore.

Comment: No worries @Karen_B, I figured it out with your guidance. v2 spoiled me with the routing attributes. Thanks!

Comment: @WillLopez I'm sure you've solved this problem by now, but I wanted to pass on a resource for adding Attributed Routing to Web API 1. http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/   I just implemented this in my project yesterday and it seems to be working well.  It handles most of the features we're used to in Web API 2.2, with some syntax differences. Also, {id:guid} is not supported, but using just {id} seems to work. NuGet: "AttributeRouting (ASP.NET WebAPI)".

Answer (score 0):

@Karen_B pointed me in the right direction but I want to provide the changes that applied in case someone else runs into this.

I changed the route mappings to:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "NewForm",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/form/",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Dmpe"
            },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new[] { HttpMethod.Post }) } 
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "GetForm",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/form/{id}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Dmpe",
                id = RouteParameter.Optional
            },
            constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new[] { HttpMethod.Get }) } 
        );
```

Then changed the controller to:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(DmpeForm form)
    {
       ....


    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(long Id)
    {
    .....
```

It may have been redundant to add the http method attributes to the methods since I changed the method names to reflect the http methods but at this point I just wanted it to work. If you have the option, use WebApi 2 :-)

Comment: Thanks for posting your final solution. I'm sure others in the community will find it helpful.